# What I'm missing? Django - Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

I'm following the example, but I guess I'm missing something, because it doesn't work

```
#views.py
def message(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "I'm in Ajax"
    else:
        message = "I'm NOT in Ajax"
    return HTTPResponse(message)

#html

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("/message", function(data){
        alert(data);
        });
            });
</script>

#urls.py
        #Display Message
        (r'^message/$', message),
```

When I refresh a page, nothing happend.
When I press F12 in Google Chrome in console it give's me an error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has no `HTTPResponse` object. You need to use a `HttpResponse` object:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

and:

```
return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: Check out network-> path-> preview to see the django rendered error page for debugging.